# How to input middle point in R?

Tags: r

There is a special character i want to input ,the middle point.

```
 "·"  #i want to input it in the R console,i paste it here,not input.
```

How to input the character middle point in R?

Comment: what do you mean by "input"?

Comment: to create it by keyboard not by mouse right click "paste."

Comment: ok... that's weird, why not create it directly in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Unicode for that:

```
"some\U00B7thing"
[1] "some·thing"
```

The middot is `\U00B7`